# How to create URL containing variables using Rest Template?

Tags: java, spring, url, resttemplate

I don't know how to create URL. I want to get the value of city from User via form. AppID and app.myserviceWeatherUrl I fetch from application.yml. How to connect URL to obtain something like this: app.myserviceWeatherUrl?q=city&app.APPID ?

```
@Service
public class WeatherClient {

@Value("{app.APPID}")
private String appID;
@Value("{app.myserviceWeatherUrl}")
private String baseUrl;

private final RestTemplate restTemplate;


public WeatherClient(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
    this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
}

public WeatherDto getWeather(String city) {
    try {
        return restTemplate.getForObject(baseUrl + city + appID, WeatherDto.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new DataNotAvailableException();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it like this:

```
 import java.net.URI;
 import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder;


 URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(baseUrl)
                .queryParam("city", city)
                .queryParam("appId", appId)
                .build().toUri();
```

So, if `baseUrl='/v1/api'`, `city='Bern'` and `appId='4'` it will be:

```
/v1/api?city=Bern&appId=4
```

And then pass uri to `getForObject()` method:

`restTemplate.getForObject(uri, WeatherDto.class);`

Answer (score 0):

Use the Java class that is cunningly named [URL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html).